# Portable Media PC Wifi Signal

Tags: usb, wifi, hardware, signal-processing, signal-strength

I set out to build myself a [custom portable media PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpw4O.jpg) using a Raspberry Pi & an electronics enclosure.

Building and testing has gone well, with the exception of my wireless signal.
I have an Edimax USB Wifi dongle hosted inside the aluminium case, and when i close the case up, the thick aluminium (expectedly) blocks the signal completely.

I have tried soldering wires to the antenna and connecting to the case via the lid screws, but it did not work. (Sorry if that was an idiotic thing to do, I don't know much about antenna design, though the wires did seem to help when the lid's off and they're not connected to anything).

I realize I could use the external USB port, but i'd rather not clog that up, it's very useful when it comes to hooking up a keyboard or other peripherals.

Let me know if anyone has any brilliant solutions. I'd like to be able to keep the lid shut as much as possible, and run everything though that back panel I already installed the other ports into.

Thanks so much,

-3 Ninjas

Answer (score 0):

You run into issues soldering wires to the antenna because it will mess with the circuit's impedance, which is very important for correct antenna function and maximum power transfer. The very small USB Wifi dongles often contain a chip antenna which is impossible (basically) to modify and extend.

I would find another USB WiFi dongle with an external antenna. These are often are connected with an SMA connector (or similar) which can be extended with a small SMA-F to SMA-M cable and can be bought from most electronics distributors.  This cable can then be brought out to a bulkhead connector on your enclosure, which you can connect to an external antenna like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/145).  You may get lucky and find a USB dongle with an onboard U.FL connector which may save some space when running cable to the enclosure wall for an SMA antenna.  Keep in mind that many of these antennas are 2.4GHz and may not work with 5GHz 802.11n bands.